# Calculate molecular weight based on chemical formula

Tags: c#

I am trying to write a program which will calculate the molecular weight of a given molecule based on its chemical formula.

This code can split a molecular formula like `"CH3OH"`  to an array `{C  H  3  O  H}` but from here, what would be a good way to use the split text to calculate the molecular weight?

```
string input = MoleculeTextbox.text;
string pattern = @"([0-9]?\d*|[A-Z][a-z]{0,2}?\d*)";
string[] sunstrings = Regex.Split(input,pattern);
```

Comment: Its molecular weight depends on whether the textbox is displayed on CRT, LCD or Plasma, at what resolution it is displayed and what the DPI is... If you want to type a molecule's name and display the weight, you'll have to have some lookup table containing atoms and their weights and combine them from the molecule the user entered.

Comment: We can't help with a problem you haven't explained, we have no idea what your problem is. Post your code and explain what the problem is with it.

Comment: I have tried regex.split to split the text. This can split it as it should, but the problem is to get it calculated, that is not working with regex.split.

Comment: @Trexten ehh.. what?

Comment: What are trying to split? You seem to assume that we can read your mind. Give us an example of what you want to split/do.

Comment: @Klaus I assume OP wants to go from "H2O" -> "H" + "H" + "O" -> "1.008" + "1.008" + "15.999". OP: we need to see your code and a specific problem description in order to help you.

Comment: @CodeCaster sounds very plausible.

Comment: I have now written the code we have used so far, at the specfic part. At the top.

Comment: I'm not a chemist so I am not sure how you would "calculate" the molecular weight of an element, I imagine you would have to look it up in a table of some sort.

Comment: The best way to get help here is to first try something. If you get stuck, do some research, make an attempt at fixing things yourself, and only then ask a specific question about your attempts, showing what you have tried. Questions asking for complete solutions without demonstrating research effort usually get downvoted and closed.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you'd need to parse the string and turn "H3" into "HHH", etc. That might look something like this:

```
var x = "CH3OH".replace(/([a-z])([2-9])/gi, function(_,c,n) { return new Array(1+parseInt(n)).join(c); });
```

First group being the matched character, and second group being the number of repetitions.

You now have a string that looks like `"CHHHOH"`. You can split that line into an array with one character at each index, `.split('')`, and map each value to its molecular mass. For that you need to define some sort of lookup table. I'm using `reduce` to take care of the mapping and the addition in one go:

```
var mass = { C: 12.011, H: 1.008, O: 15.999 };
var weight = x.split('').reduce(function(sum,element) { return sum + mass[element]; }, 0);
```

Comment: Does anyone have a final working code?